# pywin32 - Dispatch("ScriptControl") - Class not registered - Win10x64

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, windows10, vbscript

Estoy intentando correr un vbscript en Python 3.7.9 bajo Windows 10 64bit pero me funciona perfectamente en Win10x32.  Me he asegurado de instalar todas las dependencias en x64.

Este es mi código:

```
import win32com.client as win

vbscript = win.Dispatch("ScriptControl")
vbscript.language = "vbscript"
vbscript.addcode('Main\n\
Sub Main\n\
msgbox("Hola Im vbscript and I live in python!")\n\
End Sub\n')
##vbscript.addcode('Main\nSub Main\nmsgbox("Hola Im vbscript and I live in python!")\nEnd Sub\n')
try:
    vbscript.eval("Main")
except:
    pass
```

Y obtengo este error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 81, in _GetGoodDispatch
> IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\vbsinpython.py", line 4,
> in 
> vbscript = win.Dispatch("ScriptControl")   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client_*init*_.py",
> line 95, in Dispatch
> dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)   File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 98, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
> return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py",
> line 83, in _GetGoodDispatch
> IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class
> not registered', None, None)

He buscado en google y no encuentro una referencia que pueda entender. Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sufeando en la web me tope que esta solución:

**Tablacus Scripting Control** es la alternativa de 64 bits de msscript.ocx. Microsoft no tiene y no planea hacer un Control de Script de 64 bits. Script Control es una herramienta muy poderosa y fácil de usar cuando desea realizar algunas secuencias de comandos en su aplicación. Este tutorial lo guiará con la base del Control de secuencias de comandos Tablacus de 64 bits .

Control de secuencias de comandos permite a los usuarios ejecutar algunas secuencias de comandos sobre la marcha sin volver a compilar su aplicación.

La esencia de Tablacus Scripting Control es el **tsc64.dll** que debe registrar como biblioteca COM . Puede lanzar ese archivo en % WINDIR% \ System32 (opcional) y ejecutar el siguiente comando con privilegios de administrador.

Lo pueden descargar desde aquí:
https://tablacus.github.io/scriptcontrol_en.html

Les dejo la fuente:

https://helloacm.com/quick-tutorial-to-64-bit-tablacus-scripting-control/